# Unable to join Photo Stream on OS X 10.8.5

Tags: macbook-pro, icloud, photos.app, photo-stream

I received an email invitation to join a Photo Stream. When I clicked on the "Join this Photo Stream" link on my MacBook Pro, I was taken to a page with the following message:

> Photo Stream
>
> Follow these steps to join a shared photo stream
>
> 1. Make sure you have an iPhone, iPad or iPod touch running iOS 6 or a Mac running OS X 10.8.2 with iPhoto 9.4 or Aperture 3.4 or later
>    installed.
> 2. Sign in to iCloud on your devices.
> 3. Open the invitation email on an updated device and tap the Join this Photo Stream button.

I was running OS X 10.8 at the time, so I upgraded my OS, and I now have 10.8.5. However, when I click on the link to join, I still am taken to the same page. There doesn't seem to be a caching issue, because I cleared my cache and also opened the link in a different browser.

I'm logged in to iCloud, and I'm able to create a Shared Photo Stream through iPhoto (v. 9.4.3) and share it with others, and they can see the photos in the stream. However, I don't see the Photo Stream that was shared with me, and I still get the above message when I click on "Join this Photo Stream" in the original email.

I already tried copy/pasting the link from the email to the browser, and I still get the same page and message. I've also restarted my machine, logged out of iCloud and back in, quit iPhoto and restarted it, and pasted the link into both Chrome and Safari after clearing the cache.

Is it possible that I need to have OS X 10.8.2 instead of 10.8.5 in order to accept the invitation to the Photo Stream?

Comment: Sometimes the links get corrupted in a email. Try copy and use the link from outside the email.

Comment: I already tried copy/pasting the link from the email to the browser, and I still get the same page and message.

Comment: Maybe you can tell us what else have you tried, so we do not waist time here.

Comment: I've restarted my machine, logged out of iCloud and back in, quit iPhoto and restarted it, and pasted the link into both Chrome and Safari after clearing the cache. I just added those details to the question. Thanks for your help and time.

Comment: Update: iCloud seems to have changed the content of the message that gets displayed when I click on the invitation. 

The main difference seems to be an "or later" after 10.8.2, but it now says (I've changed the names to XXX): 

iCloud Photo Sharing
To subscribe to XXX’s “xxx” photo stream on your iPhone, iPad, iPod touch, or Mac, open your invitation in the Mail app, and click the Subscribe button in the message.
To subscribe you need to be signed in to iCloud on:
an iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch with iOS 6 or later, or
a Mac with OS X 10.8.2 or later and iPhoto 9.4 or Aperture 3.4 or later

Answer (score 1):

No, you would not want to be on an out of date software. Try applying the most recent OS X update (10.14.6) and trying again. Software being out of date is a usual suspect of things not working as expected. All of the devices you are accessing the Stream on would need to be current as well.